# No results from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express 

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have the following situation:

```
string SelectDeb = @"select debid,naam,adres,huisnr,plaats
                        from debiteuren";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectDeb, con))                 
    {                           
        sqlAdapt.Fill(ds, TableName);
    }
}
```

The above code works very well and no problems and it gives me the rows I needed.

It is just a part of the whole code but to keep to the subject I have only written those lines here.
What is the problem?

The problem is that when I change the sql to

```
string SelectDeb = @"select debid,naam,adres,huisnr,plaats,actief 
                     from debiteuren
                     where actief = @actief";

sqlAdapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actief", true)
```

or in

```
string SelectDeb = @"select debid,naam,adres,huisnr,plaats,actief 
                     from debiteuren
                     where actief = 'True'";
```

I get NO ROWS at all!!!

It doesn't matter if I use a parameter, if I fill in the where clause without a parameter but fill in just any where clause with data, I don't get any rows

If I use the same sql directly in the database I get the expected rows.

So, what is going wrong?

I use VS2010 professional with SP1 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition

When I wrote a similar application in VS2005 with SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, I don't have problems and can use parameters.

---

EDIT:

Thank you all for answering.

The TableName is a string that represents the resultset in the dataset after the fill.
It is given as a parameter to the method (not shown)
The only problem is that i get no rows at all AFTER using the where clause.
It doesn't matter wich filter I use.
I have also tried it with a stringfield (a NVarChar in the database) and then also no rows in the resultset.
Thus, everything works fine but after one row of code, just the 'where clause' and it is not working.
I have a lot of experience (in database and in Delphi but new to C#) and never seen something like this.

The type of the column 'actief' is a bool (in the database a Bit)

The sql that works fine in the database is

select debid,naam,adres,huisnr,huisnr_toev,postbus,postcode,postc_bus,tav,plaats,tel,actief 
                                       from debiteuren 
                                       where actief = 'True'

So just the line **where actief = 'True'** works not in code in VS2010 
ALso **where actief = 1** doesn't work
And also **naam = 'Test'** doesn't work (Test does exists in the database)

Comment: You've written that you get the expected rows if you use the `same sql directly in database`. What query does return the expected rows?

Comment: What is the type of column actief? If it is a char or varchar type, then actief = 'True' makes sense, but using a boolean parameter does not make sense. If this is a bit column then the where clause should be actief = 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sqlAdapt.Fill(ds, TableName);
```

What is TableName?  It looks like you are not using the command to fill the dataset to me.

Try something like this:

```
DataSet dataset;

sqlAdapt.Fill(dataset);
```